# Adding/updating bulk data using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, while-loop

We are inserting bulk data into one of our database tables using SQL Server Management studio. Currently we are in a position where the data being sent to the database will be added to a particular row in a table (this is controlled by a stored procedure). What we are finding is that a timeout is occurring before the operation completes; at this point we think the operation is slow because of the while loop but we're unsure of how to approach writing a faster equivalent.

```
-- Insert statements for procedure here
WHILE @i < @nonexistingTblCount
BEGIN
    Insert into AlertRanking(MetricInstanceID,GreenThreshold,RedThreshold,AlertTypeID,MaxThreshold,MinThreshold) 
    VALUES ((select id from @nonexistingTbl order by id OFFSET @i ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY), @greenThreshold, @redThreshold, @alertTypeID, @maxThreshold, @minThreshold) 

    set @id = (SELECT ID FROM AlertRanking 
    WHERE MetricInstanceID = (select id from @nonexistingTbl order by id OFFSET @i ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
    AND GreenThreshold = @greenThreshold
    AND RedThreshold = @redThreshold
    AND AlertTypeID = @alertTypeID);

    set @i = @i + 1;
END
```

Where `@nonexistingTblCount` is the total number of rows inside the table `@nonexistingTbl`. The `@nonexistingTbl` table is declared earlier and contains all the values we want to add to the table.

Comment: where are you using the @id parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a loop, you should be able to insert all of the records with a single statement.

```
INSERT INTO AlertRanking(MetricInstanceID,GreenThreshold,RedThreshold,AlertTypeID,MaxThreshold,MinThreshold) 
SELECT id, @greenThreshold, @redThreshold, @alertTypeID, @maxThreshold, @minThreshold FROM @nonexistingTbl ORDER BY id
```